# GCM Client app in a Remote Emulator cant connect to local Dev Server

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-endpoints, genymotion

I have Genymotion emulator running on a different machine.I can connect to that emulator from my development machine (by **adb connect 192.168.0.105**).The GCM client app runs well in that remote machine's emulator. When I try to register that emulator into my dev server, it says "cant connect to 10.0.3.2...).If the adb is connected , why cant I connect to my dev server in another machine ? The registration stuff works WELL in a emulator in the same machine as local dev server. I set the root as follows in client app-

```
builder.setRootUrl("http://10.0.3.2:8080/_ah/api/")//also tried 192.168.0.100,which is my local dev server ip address
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your post when searching for the same error.

I found that my AVD was not using the correct Google API system image. Step 2.3 in the following link explains what to do for that issue:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Comment: please take short summary from the link. Link based answers are usually bad. It's nice to have them just for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the visibility of your devappserver.  The default listening address is "localhost".  But you probably want to set it to 0.0.0.0, by editing your build.gradle (if you're using gradle)

```
appengine {
   httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
   ...
}
```

More details about 0.0.0.0 here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/228629/is-there-an-official-name-to-the-0-0-0-0-ip-address